# GCM issues on the android client

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android app that was working previously, I had to set up the dev environment on a new PC. Everything compiles fine (i'm using Android Studio), but I get the following error:

```
11-26 15:25:22.737  15132-15132/com.sample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar
            at com.sample.views.loginregistration.LoginManager.handleRegistration(LoginManager.java:147)
            at com.sample.views.loginregistration.LoginViewFragment.onCreateView(LoginViewFragment.java:74)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:523)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It's saying it cannot find **gcm.jar** which is clearly in the project and in a folder called **libs**. These were the common issues that people reported in other SO posts. The app basically launches and then crashes on the spot... But i'm confused as the setup is correct.

Is there anything else that could be wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a build.gradle issue. You should have this in your build.gradle file

```
dependencies { 
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar') 
}
```

Once you've added that, go to `Tools` -> `Android` -> `Sync Project with Gradle Files`